# flash object not autoplay on cross domain

Tags: wordpress, flash, nginx

I'm running my wordpress site with Nginx.
I keep my flash files in another document root with different domain name 
but the same server . 
When I access those file from my website they are not autoplay . 
What is the cause of problem could be? They are working when I access them from same domain or document root . How can I solved this problem?

Comment: what is the display size of SWF files? **On Chrome** : Does it work (auto-play) if they are display size minimum w=800 by h=600? **On Firefox** : Is your SWF / Wordpress coming from an `https` location? Firefox expects SWF that loads further external data to be running from `https` site..

Comment: Best advice for working Answer... Show real testable links. Tell which browser this issue happens on?

Comment: Hi VC.One ,
sorry for delay. This issue happens on google chrome and microsoft edge . 
It's working fine on Firefox and I.E

Comment: _"When I access those file from my website they are not autoplay"_ what happens exactly? Is it a `"click to run"` issue? Or is it auto-saving the swf file (saves to disk)? Two possible meanings of _"not autoplay"_ so confirm which one to fix...

Comment: Yes , "click to run" issue

Answer (score 0):

> "click to run" issue... What is the cause of problem could be?

Your SWF are too small and are mistaken as Banner/Adverts by Chrome browser. Advert-sized SWF content **does not auto-play** if coming from a different location to the container HTML file.

**fix**:

- Set width and height to minimum : w=800 by h=600 : This lets browser know it's a **full-size** application, not just some **small** advert that needs "auto-blocking".
  An example : 
   
  `<embed src="https://example.com/files/myFlash.swf" width=800 height= 600>`

OR else...

- Put SWF in same location as HTML file. So the path should  be... 
  HTML = https://example.com/project1/myPage.html (this page shows the SWF).
  SWF = https://example.com/project1/myFlash.swf (this SWF can auto-play at any size).

Comment: Yes , It's happen as you said .When I changed the width , it's work . But is there any other possible way to use with different location ? Please.  Thank You .