# Allow Flash Popup using Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, flash

Aside from manually enabling flash on each of every sites or tweaking the browser's settings, is there a way a website can prompt an `Allow Flash` message like this [Flash Bubble in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46523789/customize-allow-flash-bubble-on-chrome)?

Because I wanted to attach this on a button so the user wont need to do it manually on their browser setting but at least click a dedicated button then the `Allow Flash` alert will show.

Answer (score 1):

To get that pop-up you must `<embed>` the SWF within your html. Set display width & height to a large size.

See (for maybe useful tips):

- [How do I make this flash file autplay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44751192/how-do-i-make-this-flash-file-autoplay)
- [swfobject.js won't display flash in chrome (works in edge)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46881757/swfobject-js-wont-display-flash-in-chrome-works-in-edge)
- [flash object not autoplay on cross domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42619406/flash-object-not-autoplay-on-cross-domain)